# E2E Testing with a Microservices ClientsModule in app.module

Tags: nestjs

In my `app.module.ts` I have an `imports` item (called `'PRODUCER_SERVICE'`) which is a `ClientsModule` (from @nestjs/microservices) with statically defined transport `Transport.Kafka`.

When unit testing the `AppController` and `AppService`, it is easy to import a 'fake' `'PRODUCER_SERVICE'` in the testing module that uses transport `Transport.TCP` (added as an `imports` item using the  `Test.createTestingModule`)

However, in an E2E setup, i.e. when using

```js
const fixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
  ]
})
```

, I would not know how to override the Kafka based `'PRODUCER_SERVICE'` into another transport. As a result it will try to connect to (a non existing) Kafka broker during the E2E test.

Is it simply an anti-pattern to include the complete `AppModule` in a `TestingModule` for E2E testing?

I am also doing a

```js
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
app.connectMicroservice({ transport: Transport.TCP })
await app.startAllMicroservices()
await app.init()
```

in my `beforeEach`, basically starting the microservices in `Transport.TCP`.

But the additional `ClientsModule` in the `imports` of the `app.module.ts` remains of transport `Transport.Kafka`

A kinda-hacky solution could be to use a `NODE_ENV=test` variable and switch to `Transport.TCP` when issuing the `ClientsModule.register` in `app.module.ts`.

Apologies for this vague description! I hope someone could explain the holy grail into E2E testing of Nest.js microservices.